# Is there a convenient way to do an `dictionary_only` in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, arrays

Where `array_only` is a function that will return only the specified key/value pairs from an array. For example, in Laravel (in PHP land), it's possible (and common) to do the following:

```
$input = [
    'firstName' => 'Joe',
    'lastName' => 'Bloggs',
    'age' => 27,
    'votes' => 1,
];

$names = array_only($input, [
    'firstName',
    'lastName',
];

// $names = [
//    'firstName' => 'Joe',
//    'lastName' => 'Bloggs',
// ];
```

Does Objective-C have anything up its sleeve for this?

Edit: Of course, in Objective-C the function I'm after would related to `NSDictionary`s not `NSArrays`. So perhaps some equivalent for a `dictionary_only` method is what I'm looking for.

Comment: it sounds like you're looking for what a ["`NSDictionary`"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/index.html) can do

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Sorry, yep.. you're right. I've got my terminology confused. I'm after this functionality on an `NSDictionary`, with an Objective-C hat on it would be more of a `dictionary_only` function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a `dictionaryWithValuesForKeys` method:

```
[dict dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:@[@"firstName",@"lastName"]]
```

It's important to know that this is not an `NSDictionary` method. It is a part of KVC (key-value coding). So, every subclass of `NSObject` implements it, not just dictionaries. If your classes are Key-Value Coding-compliant, you can use this method to get values of arbitrary named properties.

Answer (score 0):

The `NSDictionary` method `objectsForKeys` method does this.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/objectsForKeys:notFoundMarker:

Comment: That's on the right track. I'd just need to build a new dictionary from the output of `objectsForKeys` because it only returns an array of `objects`, rather than a "view" of the original dictionary